# ServiceDescription not reading the secured wsdl

Tags: c#, web-services, dynamically-generated

I have a code in C# that basically read the passed WSDL to generate assembly dynamically and then we access all the methods and properties of that service.

```
/// <summary>
/// Builds an assembly from a web service description.
/// The assembly can be used to execute the web service methods.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="webServiceUri">Location of WSDL.</param>
/// <returns>A web service assembly.</returns>
private Assembly BuildAssemblyFromWSDL(Uri webServiceUri)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(webServiceUri.ToString()))
        throw new Exception("Web Service Not Found");

    XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(webServiceUri.ToString() + "?wsdl");

    ServiceDescriptionImporter descriptionImporter = BuildServiceDescriptionImporter(xmlreader);

    return CompileAssembly(descriptionImporter);
}

/// <summary>
/// Builds the web service description importer, which allows us to generate a proxy class based on the 
/// content of the WSDL described by the XmlTextReader.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="xmlreader">The WSDL content, described by XML.</param>
/// <returns>A ServiceDescriptionImporter that can be used to create a proxy class.</returns>
private ServiceDescriptionImporter BuildServiceDescriptionImporter(XmlTextReader xmlreader)
{
    // make sure xml describes a valid wsdl
    if (!ServiceDescription.CanRead(xmlreader))
        throw new Exception("Invalid Web Service Description");

    // parse wsdl
    ServiceDescription serviceDescription = ServiceDescription.Read(xmlreader);

    // build an importer, that assumes the SOAP protocol, client binding, and generates properties
    ServiceDescriptionImporter descriptionImporter = new ServiceDescriptionImporter();
    descriptionImporter.ProtocolName = "Soap";
    descriptionImporter.AddServiceDescription(serviceDescription, null, null);
    descriptionImporter.Style = ServiceDescriptionImportStyle.Client;
    descriptionImporter.CodeGenerationOptions = System.Xml.Serialization.CodeGenerationOptions.GenerateProperties;

    return descriptionImporter;
}
```

This piece of code works for all wsdls except for those that are protected or secured. The code fails at  `if (!ServiceDescription.CanRead(xmlreader))` line since it is not able to access the passed service wsdl. When I try to access the url in browser I get 500: server error. And when I login to our web application with proper authentication and then with the same session if I copy the url - I can access the wsdl. Fyi, in a different application we are calling this service dynamically by passing SM Cookies with service userid/password.

With said that, how can I do the same, dynamically access the wsdl which is secured? What changes do I need to do to pass the cookie information to access the wsdl? Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private Assembly BuildAssemblyFromWSDL(Uri webServiceUri)
{    
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(webServiceUri.ToString()))        
        throw new Exception("Web Service Not Found");    

    HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(webServiceUri.OriginalString + "?wsdl");
    wr.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password"); //replace with your credentials
    HttpWebResponse wres = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();

    XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(wres.GetResponseStream());       

    ServiceDescriptionImporter descriptionImporter = BuildServiceDescriptionImporter(xmlreader);    
    return CompileAssembly(descriptionImporter);
}
```

This will then allow you to pass credentials before getting the wsdl

Comment: thanks TBohnen! I was able to solve the issue with your sample code. Great!

Answer (score 1):

This is really nice but after BuildAssemblyFromWSDL when i try to invoke any method it again give me an error message like..

The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized. at (T)type.InvokeMember(methodName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, args);

my code to invoke a method is like...

```
public T InvokeMethod<T>(string serviceName, string methodName, params object[] args)
    {
        // create an instance of the specified service
        // and invoke the method
        object obj = this.webServiceAssembly.CreateInstance(serviceName);

        Type type = obj.GetType();

        return (T)type.InvokeMember(methodName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, args);
    }
```

Now, I don't know how to pass the credential here.. even i tried to pass that by other method but still getting un-authorized error..

Really Thanks If you can help...